# Is it possible to apply CSS on a web page with respective to URL of web page?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a basic question with CSS as am quite new to web development.

Can we apply CSS styles on a web page specific to the URL ?

I know CSS do not have if else conditions like we have for Javascript but I just to check if there is any smart way of doing it. Or it is not at all possible.

For example in javascript you do something like following:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("webpage1.com") > -1) {
.................
...................
................
}
```

Can we do something similar with CSS as well ?

Please provide me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I dont get why I have been negative voted. As I have already mentioned that its not possible but just checking if there is smart way of doing it. Please read the question completely before replying

Comment: can  load different style sheet based on url if that's what you are wanting to do. Just append a link tag in head with your script

Answer (score 1):

No. CSS has nothing that can read the URL of the page it is embedded on.

Uniquely identifying pages is usually done by adding an `id` to the `html` or `body` element.

Comment: @camccar — I think you mean HTML classes … and it doesn't, but you can't do that with CSS. You need a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect CSS with the URL of the page but you can add a class or an id to the HTML element of your pages

HTML:

```
<html class="subpage">
```

CSS:

```
.subpage{ add some rules }
```

HTML:

```
<html class="main">
```

CSS:

```
.main{ add some different rules}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not have access to edit HTML code. I can add only custom css or js script externally. Its basically a website like wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible if you don't mind running a script after your content gets loaded.

The script could get the hostname and use it as a className to attach to the element you want to change the styles based on the specific url, provided of course that the style are predefined.  Example:

HTML

```
<div id="main">Hello World</div>
... 
...
...
<script>document.getElementById("main").className = window.location.hostname.split( '.' ).join( '-' )</script>
```

CSS

```
#main {
 color : red;
} 
#main.fiddle-jshell-net {
  color : green;
}
#main.google-net {
  color : black;
}
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpanuncillo/faow1xeg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of styles to be updated - to the extent that it would be worth adding an entirely new stylesheet to the bottom of the cascade -  simply:

- create a new stylesheet (*eg.* `extra-styles.css`)
- if the condition is true, add a reference to that stylesheet to the DOM

**Eg.**

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('page1') > -1) {

    var extraStyles = document.createElement('link');
    extraStyles.setAtttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    extraStyles.setAtttribute('href', '/path/to/extra-styles.css');
    document.head.appendChild('extraStyles');

}
```